# My perl regex expression is not allowing the switch prompt to execute commands

Tags: perl

[image]I am the using a regex to match the prompt in a switch -

```
qr '[#>][\s]?$',
```

but while login to the switch the prompt looks like this -

sw-sn2410 [standalone: master] >

```
package Session;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Expect;
use IO::Pty;
use Data::Dumper;
use Time::HiRes qw(usleep);
sub new
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {    
        _hostnum => shift,
        _hostname => shift, 
        _username => shift,
        _password => shift,
        _mode => shift,
        _timeout => 300,
        _spawn_ok => 0,
        _output => "",      
        _rc => 255,
        _exp => undef,      
    };

    $self->{_exp} = _create_process($self);
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

##############################################################################
# Function Name : _create_process
#
#
# Notes : 
#   This function spawn to process based on connection mode & login to machine
##############################################################################
sub _create_process 
{
    my ($selfObj) = @_;
    my $cmdStr;
    my $exp = Expect->new;  
    my $timeout = $selfObj->{_timeout}; 

    $selfObj->{_spawn_ok} = 0;
    $selfObj->{_mode} = lc($selfObj->{_mode});

    if ($selfObj->{_mode} eq "telnet" ) 
    {
        $cmdStr  = "$selfObj->{_mode} $selfObj->{_hostname}";
    }
    elsif ($selfObj->{_mode} eq "ssh") 
    {       
        `rm -rf /.ssh`;
        $cmdStr = "$selfObj->{_mode} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $selfObj->{_username}\@$selfObj->{_hostname}";
    }
    elsif ($selfObj->{_mode} eq "rsh") 
    {       
        $cmdStr = "$selfObj->{_mode} $selfObj->{_hostname} -l $selfObj->{_username}";
    }
    else
    {
        printf("FileName : Session.pm , Can't initiate the connection !! Support not available for $selfObj->{_mode}");
        return -1;
    }       
    $exp->raw_pty(1);   
    $exp = Expect->spawn($cmdStr) or die "$selfObj->{_mode} to $selfObj->{_hostname} failure!! , Please check the connection & retry again: $!\n";
    if (!defined($exp))
    {
        print "$selfObj->{_mode} to $selfObj->{_hostname} failure!! , Please check the connection & retry again\n";     
        return -1;  
    }

    `sleep 2 `;
    $exp->log_user(0);
    $exp->log_file("$ENV{TSWORK}/session.log");
    #$SIG{WINCH} = \&_winch($exp); 
    if ((defined ($ENV{Debug}) && $ENV{Debug} > 1 ))
    {
        print ("\nFunction : _create_process\n\n");
        $exp->debug(3);
        $exp->exp_internal(0);
        $exp->log_user(1);  
    } 
    $selfObj->{_exp} = $exp;
    print ("Creating connection to $selfObj->{_hostname}...\n");
    my $rc = do_login($selfObj,$selfObj->{_hostname},$selfObj->{_username},$selfObj->{_password});
    ($rc != 0) ? return $rc : 0;
    $selfObj->{_spawn_ok} = 1;  
    #prompt setup 
    set_cmd_prompt($selfObj);   
    #$exp->slave->clone_winsize_from(\*STDIN);          
    my $winsize = pack('SSSS', 100, 5000, 0, 0);  # rows, cols, #pixelsX,
    ioctl($exp->slave(), &IO::Tty::Constant::TIOCSWINSZ, $winsize);
    return $exp;
}

##############################################################################
# Function Name : _winch
#
#
# Notes : 
#   This handler used to handle screen size change
##############################################################################
sub _winch 
{
    my ($exp) = @_;
    $exp->slave->clone_winsize_from(\*STDIN);
    kill WINCH => $exp->pid if $exp->pid;
    $SIG{WINCH} = \&_winch;
}

##############################################################################
# Function Name : do_login
#   IN => lpar - Name of the lpar/machine 
#   IN => username - username of the machine
#   IN => password - password of the machine
#
# Return Value :
#       Success : 0, any other value for failure 
#
# Notes :  
#   This fucntion used to login into machine & set the prompt 
##############################################################################
sub do_login
{
    my ($selfObj,$lpar,$username,$password) = @_;   
    my $exp = $selfObj->{_exp}; 
    my $timeout = $selfObj->{_timeout}; 
    my $rc = -1;
    $exp->send("\r");   
    $exp->expect($timeout,
               [
                    qr'[lL]ogin:[\s]?[a]?[s]?[\s]?$',
                    sub 
                    {
                        my $fh = shift;
                        $fh->send($username."\r");
                        `sleep 3 `;
                        exp_continue;
                    }
               ],
               [
                    qr'[uU]sername:[\s]?$',
                    sub 
                    {
                        my $fh = shift;
                        $fh->send($username."\rn");
                        `sleep 3 `;
                        exp_continue;
                    }
               ],
               [
                    qr'[pP]assword:[\s]?$',
                    sub 
                    {
                        my $fh = shift;
                        $fh->send($password."\r");
                        `sleep 3 `;
                        $exp->send("\r");
                        $exp->send("\r");
                        $rc = 0;
                        exp_continue;
                    }
               ],
               [
                    eof =>
                    sub 
                    {
                        print("FileName : Session.pm , ERROR: premature EOF in command execution.\n");
                    }
               ],
               [
                    timeout =>
                    sub 
                    {
                        print("FileName : Session.pm , Timeout : Command couldn't complete.\n");
                    }
               ],
               '-re', qr'[#$>:]\s?$', # wait for shell prompt, then exit expect
              );

    $exp->send("\r");
    usleep(1000);
    $exp->expect(3,
           [
                qr '[#>][\s]?$',
                sub {
                         exp_continue;
                    }
            ]
            );
    return $rc;
}


##############################################################################
# Function Name : execute_rm_cli_cmd
#   IN => cmdStr - Command to execute
#   IN => reqLog -  1 - Log is needed , 0 - Log is Not needed
#   IN => reqRC - 1 - return code is needed , 0 - return code is Not needed
#
# Return Value :
#       cmd_output - command output 
#   
# Notes : 
#   This fucntion execute the command & set command ouput & retcode into the
#   Object.
##############################################################################
sub execute_rm_cli_cmd
{
    my ($selfObj,$cmdStr,$reqLog)= @_;
    my $output;
    my $str = "$selfObj->{_hostname}\@$selfObj->{_username} # ";
    set_exp_setting($selfObj);
    if ($selfObj->{_spawn_ok} == 0) 
    {
        print("FileName : Session.pm , Connection already closed , So can't run the command. \nplease open the connection & run \n");
        return "";
    }

    print("Command    : $cmdStr\n");
    $selfObj->{_exp}->clear_accum();
    $selfObj->{_exp}->send("\r");
    $selfObj->{_exp}->expect($selfObj->{_timeout},
               [
                    qr '[#>]\s?$',
                    sub 
                    {
                        my $fh = shift;                 
                        $fh->send($cmdStr ."\r");    
                        if ( defined($reqLog) && $reqLog == 1 ) 
                        {                               
                            $fh->expect($selfObj->{_timeout}, '-re', $str);           
                            $output = $fh->exp_before();
                            $output =~ s/\Q$cmdStr\E//;
                            $output =~ s/^\s+//;
                            $output =~ s/\s+$//;
                            $selfObj->{_output} = $output;          
                            chomp($selfObj->{_output});                         
                            if (defined($selfObj->{_output})) 
                            {
                                print("Cmd_output :\n$selfObj->{_output}\n");               
                            }       
                            $fh->send_slow(1,"\r");                     
                            $fh->expect($selfObj->{_timeout}, '-re', $str );    
                            $fh->clear_accum();                             
                            $fh->send("echo \$?\r");                  
                            $fh->expect($selfObj->{_timeout}, '-re', $str );      
                            $output = $fh->exp_before();
                            $output =~ s/\Qecho \E\$\?//;
                            $output =~ s/^\s+//;
                            $output =~ s/\s+$//;    
                            $selfObj->{_rc} = $output;
                            chomp($selfObj->{_rc}); 
                            if (!defined($selfObj->{_output})) 
                            {           
                                $selfObj->{_rc} = 255;
                            }
                            print("ret_code   : $selfObj->{_rc}\n");
                        }
                        print ("\n");                       
                    }
                ],
               [
                    eof =>
                    sub 
                    {
                        print("FileName : Session.pm , ERROR: premature EOF in command execution.\n");
                        $selfObj->close_con();
                    }
               ],
               [
                    timeout =>
                    sub 
                    {
                        print("FileName : Session.pm , Timeout : Command couldn't complete.\n");
                        $selfObj->close_con();
                    }
               ],
              );

    if (defined($selfObj->{_output})) 
    {           
        return $selfObj->{_output};             
    }
}

##############################################################################
# Function Name : get_status
#
#
# Notes : 
#   Retur the status of connection
##############################################################################
sub get_status 
{
    my ($selfObj) = @_;
    my $exp = $selfObj->{_exp}; 
    my $stat = $exp->exp_exitstatus();
    $stat = (defined($stat))? $stat : 0;
    return $stat;
}

##############################################################################
# Function Name : close_con
#
#
# Notes : 
#   Close the connection.
##############################################################################
sub close_con 
{
    my ($selfObj)= @_;
    my $exp = $selfObj->{_exp}; 
    $selfObj->{_exp}->send("exit\r\r");
    $selfObj->{_spawn_ok} = 0;  
    $selfObj->{_exp}->DESTROY();
}

##############################################################################
# Function Name : set_timeout
#
#
# Notes : 
#   Set the command timeout 
##############################################################################
sub set_timeout
{
    my ($selfObj,$secs)= @_;
    $selfObj->{_timeout} = $secs;
}

##############################################################################
# Function Name : execute_switch_cmd
#   IN => cmdStr - Command to execute
#   IN => reqLog -  1 - Log is needed , 0 - Log is Not needed
#
# Return Value :
#       cmd_output - command output 
#   
# Notes : 
#   This fucntion execute the command & set output into cmd_ouput 
##############################################################################
sub execute_switch_cmd
{
    my ($selfObj,$cmdStr)= @_;
    my $output;
    set_exp_setting($selfObj);
    if ($selfObj->{_spawn_ok} == 0) 
    {
        print("FileName : Session.pm , Connection already closed , So can't run the command. \nplease open the connection & run \n");
        return "";
    }
    print("Command    : $cmdStr\n");
    if (!defined($ENV{SWITCH_TEST}))
    {
    $ENV{SWITCH_TEST} = "yes";
    $selfObj->{_exp}->clear_accum();
    $selfObj->{_exp}->send("\r");
    usleep(1000);
    $selfObj->{_exp}->expect(3,
           [
                qr '[#>]\s?$',
                sub {
                         exp_continue;
                    }
            ]
            );
    }
    $selfObj->{_exp}->send("\r");
    usleep(1000);
    $selfObj->{_exp}->expect($selfObj->{_timeout},
               [
                    qr '[#>]\s?$',
                    sub {
                            my $fh = shift;                 
                            $fh->send($cmdStr . "\r");                                      
                            $fh->expect($selfObj->{_timeout}, '-re', '[#>]\s?$' );            
                            $output = $fh->exp_before();
                            $output =~ s/\Q$cmdStr\E//;
                            $output =~ s/^\s+//;
                            $output =~ s/\s+$//;
                            $selfObj->{_output} = $output;  
                            open(FILEHANDLE, ">$ENV{TSWORK}/temp");
                            print(FILEHANDLE $output);
                            close(FILEHANDLE);
                            $selfObj->{_output} = `sed '\$d' $ENV{TSWORK}/temp`;            
                            $selfObj->{_output} =~ s/^\s+//;
                            $selfObj->{_output} =~ s/\s+$//;                    
                            chomp($selfObj->{_output});                         
                            if (defined($selfObj->{_output})) 
                            {
                                print("Cmd_output :\n$selfObj->{_output}\n");               
                            }                               
                            print ("\n");
                    }
                ],
               [
                    eof =>
                    sub 
                    {
                        print("FileName : Session.pm , ERROR: premature EOF in command execution.\n");
                        $selfObj->close_con();
                    }
               ],
               [
                    timeout =>
                    sub 
                    {
                        print("FileName : Session.pm , Timeout : Command couldn't complete.\n");
                        $selfObj->close_con();
                    }
               ],
              );

    if (defined($selfObj->{_output})) 
    {           
        return $selfObj->{_output};             
    }
}

##############################################################################
# Function Name : set_cmd_prompt
#
# Return Value :
#   
# Notes : 
#   This fucntion set the command prompt for the new session
##############################################################################
sub set_cmd_prompt
{
    my ($selfObj)= @_;
    if ($selfObj->{_hostnum} !~ /host/i)
    {
        return 0;
    }   
    my $output;
    my $str = '[#>]\s?$';
    my $cmdStr = "export PS1=\"$selfObj->{_hostname}\@$selfObj->{_username} # \"";
    $selfObj->{_exp}->clear_accum();
    $selfObj->{_exp}->send("\r");
    $selfObj->{_exp}->expect($selfObj->{_timeout},
               [
                    qr '[#$>:][\s]?$',
                    sub 
                    {
                        my $fh = shift;                 
                        $fh->send($cmdStr. "\r"); 
                        $fh->expect($selfObj->{_timeout}, '-re', '[#>][\s]?$' );                            
                    }
                ],
               [
                    eof =>
                    sub 
                    {
                        print("FileName : Session.pm , ERROR: premature EOF in command execution.\n");
                        $selfObj->close_con();
                    }
               ],
               [
                    timeout =>
                    sub 
                    {
                        print("FileName : Session.pm , Timeout : Command couldn't complete.\n");
                        $selfObj->close_con();
                    }
               ],      
              );

    $selfObj->{_exp}->send("\r");
    usleep(1000);
    $selfObj->{_exp}->expect(3,
           [
                qr '[#>][\s]?$',
                sub {
                         exp_continue;
                    }
            ]
            );
}

sub set_exp_setting
{
    my ($selfObj) = @_;
    $selfObj->{_output} = "";
    $selfObj->{_rc} =  255; 
    if ((defined ($ENV{Debug}) && $ENV{Debug} > 1 ))
    {
        $selfObj->{_exp}->debug(3);
        $selfObj->{_exp}->exp_internal(0);
        $selfObj->{_exp}->log_user(1);  
        print Dumper $selfObj;
    }
    else 
    {
        $selfObj->{_exp}->debug(0);
        $selfObj->{_exp}->exp_internal(0);
        $selfObj->{_exp}->log_user(0);  
    }
    $selfObj->{_exp}->notransfer(0) ;
    $selfObj->{_exp}->clear_accum();
}

##############################################################################
# Function Name : execute_rm_icli_cmd
#   IN => cmdStr - Command to execute
#
# Return Value :
#       cmd_output - command output 
#   
# Notes : 
#   This fucntion execute the command & set cmd_ouput 
##############################################################################
sub execute_rm_icli_cmd
{
    my ($selfObj,$cmdStr)= @_;
    my $output;
    my $str = '[#>] ?$';
    set_exp_setting($selfObj);
    if ($selfObj->{_spawn_ok} == 0) 
    {
        print("FileName : Session.pm , Connection already closed , So can't run the command. \nplease open the connection & run \n");
        return "";
    }

    print("Command    : $cmdStr\n");
    $selfObj->{_exp}->clear_accum();
    $selfObj->{_exp}->send("\r");
    $selfObj->{_exp}->expect($selfObj->{_timeout},
               [
                    qr '[#>]\s?$',
                    sub 
                    {
                        my $fh = shift;                 
                        $fh->send($cmdStr. "\r");                           
                        $fh->expect($selfObj->{_timeout}, '-re', $str );              
                        $output = $fh->exp_before();
                        $output =~ s/\Q$cmdStr\E//;
                        $output =~ s/^\s+//;
                        $output =~ s/\s+$//;
                        $selfObj->{_output} = $output;          
                        chomp($selfObj->{_output});                         
                        if (defined($selfObj->{_output})) 
                        {
                            print("Cmd_output :\n$selfObj->{_output}\n");               
                        }       
                        print ("\n");                       
                    }
                ],
               [
                    eof =>
                    sub 
                    {
                        print("FileName : Session.pm , ERROR: premature EOF in command execution.\n");
                        $selfObj->close_con();
                    }
               ],
               [
                    timeout =>
                    sub 
                    {
                        print("FileName : Session.pm , Timeout : Command couldn't complete.\n");
                        $selfObj->close_con();
                    }
               ],
              );

    if (defined($selfObj->{_output})) 
    {           
        return $selfObj->{_output};             
    }
}

sub execute_rm_cli_cmd_noscreen_output
{
    my ($selfObj,$cmdStr,$reqLog)= @_;
    my $output;
    my $str = "$selfObj->{_hostname}\@$selfObj->{_username} # ";
    set_exp_setting($selfObj);
    if ($selfObj->{_spawn_ok} == 0) 
    {
        print("FileName : Session.pm , Connection already closed , So can't run the command. \nplease open the connection & run \n");
        return "";
    }
    $selfObj->{_exp}->clear_accum();
    $selfObj->{_exp}->send("\r");
    $selfObj->{_exp}->expect($selfObj->{_timeout},
               [
                    qr '[#>][\s]?$',
                    sub 
                    {
                        my $fh = shift;                 
                        $fh->send($cmdStr ."\r");                           
                        if ( defined($reqLog) && $reqLog == 1 ) 
                        {                               
                            $fh->expect($selfObj->{_timeout}, '-re', $str);           
                            $output = $fh->exp_before();
                            $output =~ s/\Q$cmdStr\E//;
                            $output =~ s/^\s+//;
                            $output =~ s/\s+$//;
                            $selfObj->{_output} = $output;          
                            chomp($selfObj->{_output});                         
                            $fh->send_slow(1,"\r");                     
                            $fh->expect($selfObj->{_timeout}, '-re', $str); 
                            $fh->clear_accum();                         
                            $fh->send("echo \$?\r");                  
                            $fh->expect($selfObj->{_timeout}, '-re', $str);   
                            $output = $fh->exp_before();
                            $output =~ s/\Qecho \E\$\?//;
                            $output =~ s/^\s+//;
                            $output =~ s/\s+$//;    
                            $selfObj->{_rc} = $output;
                            chomp($selfObj->{_rc}); 
                            if (!defined($selfObj->{_output})) 
                            {           
                                $selfObj->{_rc} = 255;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
               [
                    eof =>
                    sub 
                    {
                        print("FileName : Session.pm , ERROR: premature EOF in command execution.\n");
                        $selfObj->close_con();
                    }
               ],
               [
                    timeout =>
                    sub 
                    {
                        print("FileName : Session.pm , Timeout : Command couldn't complete.\n");
                        $selfObj->close_con();
                    }
               ],
              );

    if (defined($selfObj->{_output})) 
    {           
        return $selfObj->{_output};             
    }
}

##############################################################################
# Function Name : set_oem_prompt
#
# Return Value :
#   
# Notes : 
#   This fucntion set the oem_setup_env command prompt for VIOS testing
##############################################################################
sub set_oem_prompt
{
    my ($selfObj)= @_;
    my $output;
    my $str = '[#>][\s]?$';
    my $cmdStr = "export PS1=\"$selfObj->{_hostname}\@$selfObj->{_username} # \"";
    $selfObj->{_exp}->clear_accum();
    $selfObj->{_exp}->send("\r");
    $selfObj->{_exp}->expect($selfObj->{_timeout},
                [
                    qr '[#$>][\s]?$',
                    sub
                    {
                        my $fh = shift;
                        $fh->send("oem_setup_env\r");
                        $fh->expect($selfObj->{_timeout}, '-re', '[#>][\s]?$' );

                        $fh->send($cmdStr. "\r");
                        $fh->expect($selfObj->{_timeout}, '-re', '[#>][\s]?$' );

                    }
                ],
                [
                    eof =>
                    sub
                    {
                        print("FileName : Session.pm , ERROR: premature EOF in command execution.\n");
                        $selfObj->close_con();
                    }
                ],
                [
                    timeout =>
                    sub
                    {
                        print("FileName : Session.pm , Timeout : Command couldn't complete.\n");
                        $selfObj->close_con();
                    }
                ],
            );
    $selfObj->{_exp}->clear_accum();            
}

1;
```

Due to which although i am able to login to the switch, my script is not getting the commands executed. I want to know how can i write a regex so that so that "[]" and ":" are avoided from the switch prompt?

Comment: Your pattern should match. It's not anchored to the front. Are you sure there is not additional white space behind the `>`? Also, you don't need the `[]` in the pattern for `\s`. A character group for just one type of character makes no sense. It's superfluous.

Comment: Actually there is a white space behind > in the prompt
but not in the pattern, and i have removed [] in the pattern for \s

Comment: Please [edit] and update the question then. You might want to debug print your prompt thingy with `print qq{'$prompt'} to get the exact number of spaces

Comment: I have pasted the code here